# How to list all methods of Array in Ruby programmatically?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to list all methods of `Array` in Ruby. How do I approach that?

Comment: `[].methods` try this in irb

Comment: See the [`Array documentation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html) as well as [`Enumerables`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html).

Comment: @uday it works for me, thank you

Comment: @KetanMangukiya please post a question with code

Comment: do you want list of method which exists in Array class?

Comment: Yes, @uzaif bhai.  i just want to list out all methods of Array in ruby

Comment: `[].methods`, work for me.

Comment: @KetanMangukiya at first I thought you were merely looking for the documentation (hence the downvotes I guess). After reading the comments I came to the conclusion that you want to list the `Array` methods programmatically. I've edited your question accordingly. You can avoid much confusion by showing some code. If you don't now how to write it, show the expected result.

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for the Reading it,and giving me solutions

Comment: Note that `Array.instance_methods(false)` is the same as `Array.instance_methods.select { |m| Array.instance_method(m).owner == Array }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class methods like [`Array.try_convert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-c-try_convert) can be listed via [`Objects#methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-methods)

```
Array.methods
#=> [:try_convert, :[], :allocate, :superclass, :new, :<=>, :<=, :>=, :==, ...]
```

It returns many additional methods because (`Array` being in instance of `Class`) it also includes the instance methods from `Class`. To get only the `Array` specific class methods, we can pass `false`:

```
Array.methods(false)
#=> [:try_convert, :[]]
```

---

Instance methods like [`Array#at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-at) can be listed via [`Module#instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods):

```
Array.instance_methods
#=> [:to_h, :include?, :at, :fetch, :last, ..., :instance_eval, :__id__, :__send__]
```

Again, we can pass `false` to exclude the inherited methods:

```
Array.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:to_h, :include?, :at, :fetch, :last, ..., :slice, :slice!, :dig, :hash]
```

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that the return value of `Array.instance_methods` can vary depending on what else is happening in the code. For example, `require 'set'` adds the instance method `Enumerable#to_set` and `Enumerable` is of course included by `Array`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 p Array.instance_methods(false)
```

This will list all the instance methods of array.

Comment: Well not "all" of them just the ones that are defined in `Array` this will not include `Enumerable`, `Object`, `Kernel`, and `BasicObject` methods which are technically still methods of an `Array`